# How do I ignore case in my angular 6 regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am trying to ignore case in my angular 6 regex pattern.
Not only do I want the pattern to match png, jpg, jpeg, but also match PNG, JPG, JPEG.

```
Validators.pattern('.+(\\.(pn|jpe?)g)')
```

Right now it only produces the lowercase versions.

Comment: Try `(?i)` just before your regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex literal and pass the ignore case flag, like so:

```
Validators.pattern(/.+(\.(pn|jpe?)g)/i)
```

Comment: This did not seem to work, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: The ignore case isn't being applied. It still only recognizes the lower case pattern.

Comment: @Mark Seems to work fine when I test it in a StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ekyyef?file=src/app/app.component.ts